# Adding elements to list from function arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

Define a procedure, add_to_index, that takes 3 inputs:
an index: [[,[,...]],...]
a keyword: String
a value: String

If the keyword is already in the index, add the value to the list of value's associated with that keyword.

If the keyword is not in the index, add an entry to the index: [keyword,[value]]

I wrote the following code :

```
index = []
def add_to_index(index,keyword,value):
    for entry in index :
        if entry[0] == keyword :
            entry[1].append(value)
        return
    index.append([keyword,[value]])
    return index
```

and when testing it out with the following:

```
add_to_index(index,'python','python api')
add_to_index(index,'computing','basics of computing')
add_to_index(index,'python','python tutorial')
print index
```

My expected output is:

```
[['python', ['python api', 'python tutorial']], ['computing', ['basics of computing']]]
```

But I am getting:

```
[['python', ['python api', 'python tutorial']]]
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong, please help

Comment: Are you returning from the function too early? And ... If ```entry``` is in ```index``` do something,  __else__ do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because you return from `add_to_index` too early.

Your code does only one iteration and returns from the function. You need to indent `return` (probably do `return index`)

```
index = []
def add_to_index(index,keyword,value):
    for entry in index :
        if entry[0] == keyword :
            entry[1].append(value)
            return
    index.append([keyword,[value]])
    return
```

Tested it and it works!

```
In [38]: add_to_index(index,'python','python api')

In [39]: add_to_index(index,'computing','basics of computing')

In [40]: add_to_index(index,'python','python tutorial')

In [41]: print index
[['python', ['python api', 'python tutorial']], ['computing', ['basics of computing']]]
```